# How do I make LINQ queries to an SQLite database?

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

The `System.Data.SQLite` namespace includes a sub-namespace, `System.Data.SQLite.Linq`, which the [website](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki) claims provides LINQ support. However, I can find no documentation of how to actually use it. In the following piece of code, what kind of object must `table` be, and how do I create one?

```
var rows = 
    from row in table
    where row.Id == 4345
    select column1, column2
```

Comment: Do you have an existing database?

Comment: https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6-and-the-repository-pattern/

Comment: I do have an existing database. I just need to read from it, never modify it.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't use the library that you mentioned. So I can't tell why it is not working.

However, I think you may want to try the open source [Sqlite.Net library](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). Even better is [Sqlite.Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) which supports one-to-many relationships etc.

I am using the latter (PCL version) in my Xamarin project successfully with linq queries.